# React. Присвоение класса тегу по таймауту. Как реализовать?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, settimeout

Всем привет! У меня в jsx есть кнопка, отвечающая за лайк, и в неё я хочу добавить сложную анимацию. Сложность в том, что несколько классов должны присваиваться с некоторым промежутком времени. То есть кликнули, присвоился класс, через секунду второй. Компонента функциональная. Как правильно подойти к решению этой задачи? У меня все идеи сводятся к тому, что нужно юзать state (я использую redux), но это кажется избыточным. Простые решения, вроде функции, возвращающей классы по setTimeout, не заработали.

Сейчас у меня код выглядит примерно так.

```
    const likeAnimation = s.animation + ' ' + s.someClass;
    
    return (
      <button
         onClick={() => toggleLike ()}
         className={s.likeButton + ' ' +
           (props.photo.liked_by_user ? '' : likeAnimation)
      }>
         {props.photo.likes}
      </button>
    )
```

Без таймаута всё хорошо работает. Задача в том, чтобы по клику сначала добавился s.animation, а через определённое время s.someClass.

Примеры моего неработающего кода с использованием setTimeout приводить не буду - их было много и я вконец запутался.

Comment: анимировать react компоненты через setTimeout, довольно скользкий путь. Советую посмотреть в сторону https://www.react-spring.io/

Comment: проще всего подключить какую-нибудь библеотеку для анимации, например `mo-js`   https://mojs.github.io/